# type '() => Future<List<Food>>' is not a subtype of type <List<Food>

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await

I am new to flutter. when I run my code , I got the error

```
 E/flutter (16181): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: Unhandled error type '() => Future<List<Food>>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Food>' occurred in Instance of 'MenuBloc'.
E/flutter (16181): #0      MenuBloc.mapEventToState (package:restuarant_app/Bloc/menue_bloc/menu_bloc.dart:30:7)
E/flutter (16181): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (16181): #1      Bloc._bindEventsToStates.<anonymous closure> (package:bloc/src/bloc.dart:232:20)
E/flutter (16181): #2      Stream.asyncExpand.onListen.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/stream.dart:579:30)
E/flutter (16181): #3      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1192:38)
E/flutter (16181): #4      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1085:19)
E/flutter (16181): #5      _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:987:7)
E/flutter (16181): #6      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:339:11)
E/flutter (16181): #7      _DelayedData.perform (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:594:14)
E/flutter (16181): #8      _StreamImplEvents.handleNext (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:710:11)
E/flutter (16181): #9      _PendingEvents.schedule.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:670:7)
E/flutter (16181): #10     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1180:38)
E/flutter (16181): #11     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1077:19)
E/flutter (16181): #12     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:979:7)
E/flutter (16181): #13     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1019:23)
E/flutter (16181): #14     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1184:13)
E/flutter (16181): #15     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1077:19)
E/flutter (16181): #16     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:979:7)
E/flutter (16181): #17     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1019:23)
E/flutter (16181): #18     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:43:21)
E/flutter (16181): #19     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:52:5)
E/flutter (16181): 
E/flutter (16181): #0      Cubit.onError.<anonymous closure> (package:bloc/src/cubit.dart:140:7)
E/flutter (16181): #1      Cubit.onError (package:bloc/src/cubit.dart:141:6)
E/flutter (16181): #2      Bloc.onError (package:bloc/src/bloc.dart:113:11)
E/flutter (16181): #3      _rootRunBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1204:38)
E/flutter (16181): #4      _CustomZone.runBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
E/flutter (16181): #5      _CustomZone.runBinaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:995:7)
E/flutter (16181): #6      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendError.sendError (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:358:15)
E/flutter (16181): #7      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendError (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:376:16)
E/flutter (16181): #8      _BufferingStreamSubscription._addError (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:275:7)
E/flutter (16181): #9      _SyncBroadcastStreamController._sendError.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/broadcast_stream_controller.dart:393:20)
E/flutter (16181): #10     _BroadcastStreamController._forEachListener (dart:async/broadcast_stream_controller.dart:327:15)
E/flutter (16181): #11     _SyncBroadcastStreamController._sendError (dart:async/broadcast_stream_controller.dart:392:5)
E/flutter (16181): #12     _BroadcastStreamController._addError (dart:async/broadcast_stream_controller.dart:294:5)
E/flutter (16181): #13     _rootRunBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1204:38)
E/flutter (16181): #14     _CustomZone.runBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
E/flutter (16181): #15     _CustomZone.runBinaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:995:7)
E/flutter (16181): #16     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendError.sendError (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:358:15)
E/flutter (16181): #17     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendError (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:376:16)
E/flutter (16181): #18     _BufferingStreamSubscription._addError (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:275:7)
E/flutter (16181): #19     _ForwardingStreamSubscription._addError (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:139:11)
E/flutter (16181): #20     _ForwardingStream._handleError (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:104:10)
E/flutter (16181): #21     _ForwardingStreamSubscription._handleError (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:170:13)
E/flutter (16181): #22     _rootRunBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1204:38)
E/flutter (16181): #23     _CustomZone.runBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
E/flutter (16181): #24     _CustomZone.runBinaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:995:7)
E/flutter (16181): #25     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendError.sendError (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:358:15)
E/flutter (16181): #26     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendError (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:376:16)
E/flutter (16181): #27     _DelayedError.perform (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:605:14)
E/flutter (16181): #28     _StreamImplEvents.handleNext (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:710:11)
E/flutter (16181): #29     _PendingEvents.schedule.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:670:7)
E/flutter (16181): #30     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1180:38)
E/flutter (16181): #31     _C
```

I would like to get data from remote server.I use bloc library in my code.
This is part of menue_bloc.dart .I got error on line  `allFood= await _foodRepositiry.getAllFood() ;`.

```
class MenuBloc extends Bloc<FoodEvent, MenuState> {
  final _foodRepositiry = FoodRepository();
  Map<String, List<Food>> mapFoodList;

  MenuBloc({this.mapFoodList=const{}}) : super(InitialMenuState());
 @override
  // TODO: implement initialState
  MenuState get initialState => InitialMenuState();

  @override
  Stream<MenuState> mapEventToState(FoodEvent event) async* {
    print("loading....");
    yield Loading();
    if (event is GetAllFoodEvent) {
      print("Get all food....");
      this.mapFoodList = {};
      List<Food> allFood;

      allFood= await _foodRepositiry.getAllFood() ;
                try {
        print("in menu bloc...... ");

        allFood.forEach((food) {
          print(food.toString());
          if (!this.mapFoodList.containsKey(food.category)) {
            this.mapFoodList[food.category.toString()] = [];
          }

          this.mapFoodList[food.category].add(food);
        });

        yield Loaded(mapFoodList: this.mapFoodList);
      } catch (e, stacktrace) {
        print(e.toString());
        print(stacktrace.toString());
```

When I change `List<Food> allFood;`to `Future<List<Food>> allFood;` it gives me following error

```
I/flutter (16181): type '() => Future<List<Food>>' is not a subtype of type 'Future<List<Food>>'
```

This FoodRepository code.

```
class FoodRepository{
  final foodDao=new FoodDao();
  final foodApiClient =new FoodApiClient();
  Future getAllFood() async{
    if(await checkInternetConnection()) {
      print("fetch data from remote server");
     return  foodApiClient.fetchAllFood;
    }else{
     print("from db");
     return foodDao.getAllFood();
   }

  }
}
```

This is FoodApiClient code:

```
class FoodApiClient{
  static const baseUrl = '10.0.2.2';
  final http.Client httpClient;

  FoodApiClient({this.httpClient});
  Future<List<Food>> fetchAllFood()async{
    String url=":8080/resturant/food/allFood";
   // print(url);
    List<Food> foodList;
    print(url);
    final allFoodResponse=await httpClient.get(baseUrl+url);
    print(allFoodResponse);
    if (allFoodResponse.statusCode != 200) {
      throw Exception('An error occured while loading food list!!! status code: '+allFoodResponse.statusCode.toString());
    }
    print("foodJson");
    List foodJson = json.decode(allFoodResponse.body);
    print(foodJson);
    //foodJson.forEach((food) {foodList.add(Food.fromJson(food)); });
    foodList=foodJson.map((f)=>Food.fromJson(f)).toList();
    return   foodList;
  }

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a Future and how do I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63017280/what-is-a-future-and-how-do-i-use-it)

Comment: First, make a simpler project without Bloc and make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Future getAllFood() async{
```

needs to be

```
Future<List<Food>> getAllFood() async {
```

and then you need to follow the compiler errors from there, because there are a lot more instances that I cannot all name and describe here.

---

I strongly advise you to use proper dart formatting, and the package [pedantic](https://pub.dev/packages/pedantic) to tell you all about your code and how to improve it if you cannot find those places yourself.

Comment: When I altered according  your suggession I get this error                        Compiler message:
lib/Repository/FoodRepository.dart:12:28: Error: A value of type 'Future<List<Food>> Function()' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'FutureOr<List<Food>>'.
 - 'Future' is from 'dart:async'.
 - 'List' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'Food' is from 'package:restuarant_app/Model/Food.dart' ('lib/Model/Food.dart').
 - 'FutureOr' is from 'dart:async'.
     return  foodApiClient.fetchAllFood;

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I told you. Can you spot your mistake?

Comment: sorry I can't ,I don't know what to do

Comment: Is that supposed to be a function call? Maybe you missed the `()`?

Comment: `return foodApiClient.fetchAllFood;` needs a set of `()`, because it's supposed to be a function call.

Comment: **@nvoigt** Thank you.I get another error unhandled Exception: Unhandled error NoSuchMethodError: The method 'get' was called on null.I keep on going